# Accessing wordpress in aws ec2 on port 80. Cannot connect to port 80

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a wordpress website on an aws ec2 (Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0).

I use docker-compose to spin up the website, database and phpmyadmin.

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  data:
networks:
  back:

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: test
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      - back

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    container_name: site
    networks:
      - back

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      - back
```

As you see I am mapping port 80 in my container to port 80 of my host. This should make the website available on my IPv4 Public IP. I think I have inbound access correctly configured in my security group.

[image: security groups]

I cannot access my website on port 80. When I change the yml file to map port 80 of my container to 8080 on my host it does work.
What do I have to do to make the website available on port 80?

**Continued:**
I ran docker compose as root with:
sudo `which docker-compose`up -d 
The website was still unreachable.

I removed docker-compose from /usr/local/bin and installed it in /usr/bin.
Then I ran sudo docker-compose up -d
The website was still unreachable.

Still I think it indeed has something to do with running it as root. I can find the website when I run it on anything above port 1024. I cannot see it when running it on a port below 1024.

In which directory should I install docker-compose to run it as root?

I am sure the docker containers are coming up. I can see this as output from docker ps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not running `docker compose` as `root`. Basically ports below `1024` are privileged ports and hence you need to be root to run processes that listen on these ports.
Run docker compose using using `sudo` and you should be able to access the site using port 80 and your hosts public IPV4 Address.

Comment: I tried running it as `sudo which docker-compose ..`  . It ran docker-compose as before. Still, when visiting from a browser port 80 is unreachable. I guess it indeed has something to do with running as root, cause non of the ports under 1024 is working